# How come the first 200 characters of the text are not shown?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I'm creating a page to show a list of news articles.  I want to show the first 200 characters of the text.  I store my data in mySQL.  Everyone works except that it's not displaying the first 200 characters of the text.  It displays about 30 characters.  I've been looking at my code for a long time and tried the "rereplace" method but it doesn't work.  Can someone give me a hint on what's missing?  Thanks a lot!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Almost done?</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <!--- Page Title --->
    <h3>Article Listings</h3>

    <!--- Page Content --->
    <!--- Display article title, author, date, first 200 characters
    of the article content and a link to view the full article --->
    <div align="left">
        <cfoutput query="myQuery1">
            <b><a href="full_article_view.cfm?ID=#article_ID#" style="color:##000000; text-decoration: none;">#ucase(myquery1.article_title)#</a></b>
            <hr>
            <p style="color:##848181; font-size:12px">#myquery1.article_author# :: #myquery1.article_date#</p>
            <cfset nonhtml=reReplace(myquery1.article_content, "<[^>]*>","","ALL")>
            #LEFT(nonhtml, 200)# ... <a href="full_article_view.cfm?ID=#article_ID#">Read More</a>
            <br><br><br>
        </cfoutput>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your text contains HTML, you're removing it at the "CFSET nonhtml=" line. Without the HTML, is it possible that the content of myquery1.article_content could already be less than 200 characters?

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  Start with article_content.  See how many characters it has.  Then look at nonhtml.  If that looks like it has at least 200 characters, output #len(left(nonhtml))#.  If it's still a mystery, look at the html source code.  Maybe an angle bracket is causing something to be hidden.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: Thanks for the tip.  I just checked #len(left(nonhtml))#.  It says 200.  I'm very new to coldfushion.  I looked at my code many times, but I'm still not sure what I'm missing in the code.

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo: I checked #len(left(nonhtml))#. It says 200.  I store everything in a mysql database as text. I have a very long paragraph with 600 characters.

Comment: But what *are* those 200 characters? Are the all printable? What do you see if you view-source (or just dump out the string, instead of outputting it).

Comment: Those are printable words from an article (including letter, space, comma, period, space, etc). When I tried cfdump on nonhtml, it shows me the whole content.  It seems like the reReplace() did not chop out space, comma, and period..

Comment: If you dump the variable and then output it, what is the first character of the former that does not appear in the latter?

Comment: Their output is the same.  I wonder if the reReplace() is working.

Comment: Wouldn't #len(left(nonhtml))# throw error? Considering second argument count is mandatory for LEFT function? Other thing is, is it showing this way for all iterations of the loop (if there are more than one results for your query) or just for one specific?

Answer (score 0):

i tried out your code and i got 200 characters, but i used a long text with html for the *myquery1.article_content*

First i would fix, that also shorter posts than 200 characters don't throw an error:

```
<! --- ... --->
<cfset nonhtml=reReplace(myquery1.article_content, "<[^>]*>","","ALL")>
<cfif len(nonhtml) GT 200>
  #LEFT(nonhtml, 200)# ... <a href="full_article_view.cfm?ID=#article_ID#">Read More</a>
<cfelse>
  #nonhtml#
</cfif>
```

Second, i don't like the fact, that words are split, or in other words a sentence is interrupted inside a word. Because of that i would suggest to use this function: http://www.cflib.org/udf.cfm/fullleft

by the way: Raymond Camden has a cool [article](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2008/5/28/Ask-a-Jedi-Best-way-to-trim-text) about this: